# As a super-natural, how do I really transfer into a school

Tags: internal-consistency

Aliens, robots, Biblical creatures disguised as a cute girl transfers into [protagonist] school is a cliche.

But, how do I really do it?

Assume,

Local skin tone, Accent, Mid-class and other average student physical characteristics. The being has sufficient common sense and mental health to not look out of the ordinary.

But, has no, ID card, birth certificate , basically in the eyes of the government doesn't exist. Like just pop out of nowhere. Like a bastard born child kept quiet or something.

How to solve this assuming mind-control and all manner of magic is out of the question. Actually does not have to be a super-natural in the first place.

Comment: Pulse: I doubt any current school would admit any girl without any document at all. If your girl has nothing, at least she has to falsify some (so I suggest that may be the first step: building a fake profile).

Comment: Welcome to woldbuilding! The question is a bit broad, could you narrow it down by specifying a place and time frame? Perhaps also how far in advance it can be planned. 
Is it allowed to control the school or must teachers/head master etc be duped?

Comment: Read Orson Scott Card's "Mither Mages" sets.  This is a problem that the protagonist has to resolve.

Comment: "*Aliens, robots, Biblical creatures*" **all** "*disguised as a (single) cute girl*"?  I've very confused.

Comment: As a fun anecdote - I had 2 friends who tried "changing school" by literally just walking into the classes of another school and sitting down. They managed to get through half the day before eventually being caught out (from disrupting a class, and then being sent to management). It's not what you're asking for - but at least it does add some plausibility to a more careful scheme actually working.

Comment: What "age" does the girl look like? What country (as in some of these, she could turn in as abandoned and if below certain age be put in school by gov or will simply be allowed to go to public schools despite undocumented status; if older....)? Age and region will play a huge role in how one would move from undocumented to documented status in a country (or at primary level - just go to school in an undocumented status).

Comment: I can second @Bilkokuya's friends' experience - I did the same myself.  Joined my friends' classes in a new year, feigned surprise that I wasn't on the register, and the "mistake" was quickly corrected.  I made it through a couple of months before a staff member who knew me personally spotted me and tried to work out what was going on.  A complete stranger is not going to have this problem, and in any world where education isn't strongly regulated, teachers are not likely to care about minor administrative discrepancies.

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle The fact yours actually worked so far as getting multiple months of not being spotted, and actually managing to get put on the registers - I think is worth posting as an answer. There's nothing better than "I did this, this is how".

Comment: @RonJohn You mean your copy of the Bible *doesn't* include "The Book of Revelations, Part 2: Ultra-Jesus Vs. Mecha-Devil-chan from Mars"?

Comment: Just send her to the good old USA. We have these things called "sanctuary cities" where she can become a "dreamer". She can get a better deal than the local citizens, in many circumstances.

Comment: * Pre-Trump USA

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**What age is she?**

Where I live undocumented children will have no problem getting into elementary school as it is considered a human right. She will have to be able to convince the school that she is a "proper" undocumented alien though, as opposed to an abductee or something. Any sign of abuse or neglect on her will get the authorities involved very quickly. Being fluent in a foreign language might help her keep up the appearance.

Higher education is a problem. She is gonna need a social security number and some means of identification. These can be forged however, and as long as she avoids scrutiny she will be fine, nobody will investigate. As long as all bills are payed and she plays "average student" well there will be little problem.

As another answer already mentioned though, she will have to have some people to act like her parents/guardians from time to time, for as long as she is supposed to be a minor. They do not need documents, but will have to act convincingly.

Comment: This is at least true in the US and the act is based off of [Plyler vs. Doe](http://www.k12.wa.us/MigrantBilingual/ImmigrantRights.aspx) - was going to add this as an answer but you beat me to it but thought the case might add something :)

Comment: I will add one minor correction - parents will not need documents proving status but they will need a birth certificate or other paperwork  (can be from a foreign country) showing guardianship of the child.

Comment: @JGreenwell I'm pretty sure I was present for all the administrative stuff when I switched schools at age 12 or so and no birth certificate or proof of guardianship was necessary (and my guardian didn't even have the same last name as me). That was for a German "Gymnasium". They did have paperwork asking for stuff like place of birth, but would be very surprised if that was verified. Also they didn't get anything from my previous school, I'm sure about that.

Comment: @Nobody I taught primary school for two years (last year and the year before) so I can confirm this is a requirement of registering in US - note once registered at the district for Kindergarten the paperwork follows you so you don't need to re-show anything when transferring unless there is a change. Paperwork was also verified but the verification process has issues (language barriers, foreign policy, etc) so there are ways around it in terms of the story. Again, I can only confirm for US.

Answer (score 12):

If the school is big enough to have a complex bureaucratic systems the only thing required is to someone from inside (or even a hacker) to add the new students to the system.

The teachers may not care about the student life outside school, so nobody will audit or double check the archives to see from where that person came from or ask if they were really suppose to be there.

That works even better in a big city or in a community without strong ties where parents of students don't get into each others business.

Comment: Yeah, just have some "mom" go up and whine to the secretary some stuff about migrating here and paperwork being too slow but your precious preciosu child shouldn't miss its education or something.
That's it, should work with like a 50/50 chance (depending on state etc.)

Comment: In many countries - undocumented children are allowed (or even still required) to attend public school despite their status, so would only need a birth/adoption/legal guardian cert. Which the hacker could add as a faked image to cover. However, as a former elementary teacher, our state still used paper records - certified copies which transferred with the student in their student record folder - so a digital attack (by itself) wouldn't work for a new student for very long in places like this.

Answer (score 8):

**Identity theft**

1) Find a cute girl of the required age who is about to transfer into said school.

2) Occupy her body or kill her and wear her skin.

3) Brainwash the parents if necessary. Chances are the changes in her personality can just be explained by puberty.

Comment: Or you can simply kill another kid and wear their skin to school :) And here I was fussing about documents and acting convincingly.

Answer (score 5):

The question really becomes what forms of verification does the school require. Which essentially boils down to how strict does the person that "admits" students want to be. In some locations proof of being an adult that lives in district is enough to get ones "child" enrolled. So if the student had another entity, essentially a person of  parental/guardian age that could show proof of residency it would be little issue to get someone in to school. As the district becomes larger or more sought after as a place to attend shool this likely become more difficult.

Getting someone into a school with a legal age helper would be much easier than a school age person being admitted on their own though. Imagine a 16 year old walking up to a school secretary asking to get enrolled. They are far more likely to be referred to a foster organization then be allowed to attend classes without some adult to vouch for them.

Comment: Once in the foster care system they would be required to attend school.

Answer (score 2):

Greetings prinipal of prestigious private school.  I am an eccentric billionaire and I'd like to enroll my daughter.  She doesn't have any documentation because the documentation butler was actually an actor hired by my nemesis and I had to fire him.  Hopefully you can arrange all of that for me. How many sacks with a dollar bill sign on them should I leave with you?

Answer (score 1):

Have an ally with valid ID adopt the supposed child from a country with bad records, to then get valid ID for the country with the school in.  Celebrities like Madonna do so frequently!

Answer (score 1):

A couple of ways that do not involve hurting/killing anyone

1) Simply bloody yourself up and be found in an ally by the police.  Pretend you do not remember who you are and the government will likely make a perfectly legal entry in the system for you.

2) "Immigrate" from a country with bad/no records, to a friendly country (like Canada).  Again, the government will make a perfectly legal identity for you.

3) Grease the palms of the morgue staff to "forget" to file a death certificate for a Jane Doe (even better if her name is common).  Assume this person's identity.  As a magical/alien creature, you can likely trade fairy dust or ray guns easily.

4) Simply show up and act like you belong there.  Several [con artist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catch_Me_If_You_Can) have spent years playing the bureaucracy

Comment: For number 2, you don't even need to be an immigrant... assuming USA, the nation is certainly prone to a variety of disasters that can be used to circumvent documentation... as this [real life 2018 case][1] showed, when a "17 year old Hurricane Harvey Survivor" turned out to not be what he claimed to be.


  [1]: https://www.dallasnews.com/opinion/commentary/2018/05/16/find-grown-mans-posing-student-sons-dallas-high-school